# MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED, is there a way to use more then 25 waypoints?

Tags: directions

We concepted a webservice to request routes to Google Directions API, but now I'm getting MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED exception, but I do need to use more then the maximum allowed waypoints. I can't split these points in more requests becouse I'm using optimize, so I understand that if I split it, I won't get the best route through my map. Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.